# UnfinishedStubbingException for a Kotlin test

Tags: spring, kotlin, mockito

I'm converting some `Java` code to `Kotlin`, and I'm getting a `UnfinishedStubbingException` exception for the below code:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = [FormsApplication::class])
class AccountResourceIntTest {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var userRepository: UserRepository

    @Autowired
    lateinit var authorityRepository: AuthorityRepository

    @Autowired
    lateinit var userService: UserService

    @Autowired
    lateinit var passwordEncoder: PasswordEncoder

    @Autowired
    lateinit var httpMessageConverters: Array<HttpMessageConverter<*>>

    @Autowired
    lateinit var exceptionTranslator: ExceptionTranslator

    @Mock
    lateinit var mockUserService: UserService

    @Mock
    lateinit var mockMailService: MailService

    private lateinit var restMvc: MockMvc

    private lateinit var restUserMockMvc: MockMvc


    @Before
    fun setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
        doNothing().`when`(mockMailService).sendActivationEmail(any()) <-- exception
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

The stacktrace:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException: 
Unfinished stubbing detected here:
-> at com.application.web.rest.AccountResourceIntTest.setup(AccountResourceIntTest.kt:82)

E.g. thenReturn() may be missing.
Examples of correct stubbing:
    when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true);
    when(mock.isOk()).thenThrow(exception);
    doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
Hints:
 1. missing thenReturn()
 2. you are trying to stub a final method, which is not supported
 3: you are stubbing the behaviour of another mock inside before 'thenReturn' instruction if completed

    at com.application.service.UserServiceIntTest.init(UserServiceIntTest.kt:64)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    ...
```

The `MailService` `class` is marked as `open`.

```
@Service
open class MailService {
    ...
    @Async
    fun sendActivationEmail(user: User) {
        log.debug("Sending activation email to '{}'", user.email)
        sendEmailFromTemplate(user, "mail/activationEmail", "email.activation.title")
    }
}
```

The `Java` code I'm converting this test from:

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    doNothing().when(mockMailService).sendActivationEmail(any());
    ...
}
```

The error points to a missing `thenReturn` statement, but this is not required in the original `Java` code.  What is going on here?

Comment: The exception is occurring in a different class than the one you provided. It occurs in `AccountResourceIntTest`

Comment: @Dean Thanks for pointing this out.  I accidently provided the wrong class.  Updated my question now with the correct `AccountResourceIntTest` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem by adding the following code to the `AccountResourceIntTest` class

```
private fun <T> any(): T {
    Mockito.any<T>()
    return uninitialized()
}
private fun <T> uninitialized(): T = null as T
```

Explanation of the issue and how to resolve it found [here](https://medium.com/@elye.project/befriending-kotlin-and-mockito-1c2e7b0ef791).